# Flutter - How to reply to an email through enough_mail

Tags: flutter, dart, smtp, imap

I am using [enough_mail](https://pub.dev/packages/enough_mail) dependency for my mail client Flutter app. My requirement is how to reply to a mail. Here is how I build the Message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize MessageBuilder bellow way

```
MessageBuilder messageBuilder = MessageBuilder.prepareReplyToMessage(
    mimeMessage,
    MailAddress('', senderEmail),
    replyAll: false,
    quoteOriginalText: true,
    replyToSimplifyReferences: true
)
```